# Непригоден или не пригоден

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать: непригоден или не пригоден? Например, оборудование непригодно к эксплуатации. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

**Оборудование непригодно к эксплуатации.**

НЕПРИГОДНЫЙ,  Такой, который не годится для чего-л., не обладает нужными для чего-л. качествами; негодный.

**1) Чаще встречается  слитное написание: непригодный ― непригоден.**

Здание было совершенно непригодно для жилья.Эти, что в масках приезжали, так и говорили: село непригодно для жизни в течение трехсот лет!

**2) Раздельное написание частицы НЕ обычно связано с усилением отрицания:**

Какой был скарб ― все это прожито или разбито, никуда не пригодно. [Д. А. Фурманов. Мятеж (1924)] 4 процента земли совсем никуда не пригодно. [Василий Песков, Борис Стрельников. Земля за океаном (1977)]